# Why does this codebase use '// for VB.NET comments?

Tags: vb.net, comments

I've recently been working on a VB.NET codebase. The programmer behind most of the code always uses `'//` to prefix comments, e.g.

```
'// Some comment here
```

Any ideas as to why they done this, rather than just used a `'` on it's own?

```
' Some comment here
```

Comment: Have you tried asking them?

Comment: Maybe because the code was originally written in C# and the programmer has forgotten to remove them.

Comment: The usual reason is that a single quote is too thin to make it obvious enough that it is a comment.  More than one way to do it, using more than a single quote works too.  And if you are used to the curly-brace languages then // is an obvious choice.  REM is possible but generally too hokey.

Comment: Most definitely because it was created by a code converter that converted it from c# to vb.net

Comment: There are no technical reason directly related to vb.net for doing this. You should ask the person who did it. Maybe it's for esthetic, maybe they use a 3rd party program that needs it.